# Vector Displacement from Zbrush to Blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, displacement, vector, zbrush

How do I get Blender to render a vector displacement map from Zbrush properly?

I have rendered the diagnostic scene from Zbrush, but none of them are accurate enough to be useful.

I am running Blender version 2.80 build from 7th feb, 2019.

[image]

Comment: IIRC 25 is compatible with blender coordinates...which is [+X, +Y, +Z]